# managing environment variables angularjs ionic app

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, gulp, ionic-framework

I want to be able to set different url for my diff environments for my ionic app

in my gulpfile.js i have included

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var replace = require('gulp-replace-task'); 
var args    = require('yargs').argv; 
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');
var preprocess = require('gulp-preprocess');
    gulp.task('dev', function() {
      gulp.src('./js/appSettings.js')
        .pipe(preprocess({context: { NODE_ENV: 'DEVELOPMENT', DEBUG: true}}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js/'));
    });

    gulp.task('test_env', function() {
      gulp.src('./js/appSettings.js')
        .pipe(preprocess({context: { NODE_ENV: 'TEST', DEBUG: true}}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js/'));
    });

    gulp.task('prod', function() {
      gulp.src('./js/appSettings.js')
        .pipe(preprocess({context: { NODE_ENV: 'PRODUCTION'}}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js/'));
    });
```

i created a new file www/js/appSettings.js

```
AppSettings = {
  // @if ENV == 'DEVELOPMENT'
  baseApiUrl: 'http://10.0.3.2:3000/',
  debug: true
  // @endif
  // @if ENV == 'TEST'
  baseApiUrl: 'stg-partners.loanstreet.com.my/'
  // @endif
  // @if ENV == 'PRODUCTION'
  baseApiUrl: 'https://api-example.com/'
  // @endif
}
```

in my services.js

```
.factory('referralCasesGroupByCaseStatus', function($http, $q) {
  var getcaseStatusByCount = {
    caseStatusCount: function(paramsData){
      var d= $q.defer();

      var url = AppSettings.baseApiUrl + '/api/v1/case_status_count?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&username='+paramsData+'&format=json';
      $http.post(url).then(function(data) {
        if(data.status===200){
          d.resolve(data.data);
        }
        else {
          d.reject(data);
        }
      });
      return d.promise;  
    }
  return getcaseStatusByCount;
})
```

i was following this tutorial http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/08/23/managing-environment-variables-for-your-ionic-application/

In the tutorial the setup looks a bit different from a regular ionic app. Like i dont really understand what should be here  `gulp.src('./js/appSettings.js')`

cos my directory for my appSettings.js file is projectname/www/js/appSettings.js

Is there anything i am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: if your gulpfile.js is in your root, the uri shall be ./www/js/appSettings.js